# Automatic Step over

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have been getting this error message when I step into some methods

```
Do you want to continue being notified when an Automatic step over occurs?
```

I usually answer Yes and I get taken to the line I want to step to.

However, I just pressed No (cause I was tired of the dialog box always popping up).  When I did that it skipped a lot of code I wanted to step through.  Now when I step into my method it is skipping my method (and jumping to the finally block because the method I am trying to step into is throwing an exception).

How can I change my answer back to Yes?

I would prefer it never ask me (default showing the code), but if faced with the choice of it skipping the code I need to see, or having a NagBox, I will take the NagBox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand this message correctly, code is always skipped - regardless of your choice.
It's like "Hey, just a heads up, I am going to skip some code. Do you want me to notify you next time?"  Yes/No

Comment: Yeah, my bad.  I thought it was stepping over, but it was not.  (I had a null reference in one of the params.

Comment: Just fyi I choose "Yes" all the time :)

(I clicked "No" once but the popup was back later - don't know why)

Answer (score 10):

I'm blissfully unaware of this.  Try Tools + Options, Debugger, "Step over properties and operators" checkbox.  If that's not it, document the key you press.

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck Tools + Options, Debugger, "Step over properties and operators" and that will fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is still interested in this, I was able to solve my stepping into a function by doing the following

```
Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General
```

and then unselect

```
Require source files to exactly match the original version
```